# How can I get drupal8 to co-exist with other websites?

Tags: apache, drupal

I have Drupal installed in /var/www/html so it is the default page when visiting my site say https://www.foo.bar.  If I wanted to add something like Cacti, the Cacti installer breaks because drupal is trying to redirect it.  However, even if I removed htaccess file, the problem still exists.  Is there something I need to do after removing htaccess?  I would have assumed the effects are immediate (the rewrites break immediately but the redirection of /cacti/install to /cacti/install/core/install.php still happens and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to consider several things before doing something like this in production. And you definitely don't want to remove the `.htaccess` file. But, for testing purposes, you can put your Cacti directory in `/var/www/html/cacti` (or do a symlink) and then add the line `Alias "/cacti" "/var/www/html/cacti"` in either your `<VirtualHost>` section or preferred Apache config file. You should then be able to access the subdirectory at foo.bar/cacti.

Comment: Doing that, reloading the config still redirects /cacti/install to /cacti/install/core/install.php.  The issue I think is that the htaccess specifically says installs are verboten or something.  Hence why I tried hiding htaccess.  I am able to have children directories (i have several things co-existing but the Cacti installer isn't able to run.  I tried renaming it to say fooinstall but too many things are hard coded and too lazy to sed everything.